# ROS Answers SE migration: vslam beginner

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using vslam package first time. We have done 2D mapping gmapping to generate a static map. Now, our plan is to generate a 3D static map using a VSLAM. Is it possible to generate a static 3D map using VSLAM? If yes, then what are the steps to do so?

I have gone through SBA and VSLAM packages but unable to understand the process. We have Minoru stereo cam by which we can generate rectified images left/ right and can give it to vslam.

I also tried the sba tutorial. I get below error while compiling the package.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsba_ros

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[3]: *** [../bin/sba_from_file] Error 1

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sba_from_file.dir/all] Error 2

Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10816/vslam-beginner/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-08-08**:
There are two questions here ("how do I use vslam?" and "why won't it compile"?) You should break these into two questions. (Also, there are a great many vslam-related questions here; have you read through those?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vslam is experimental research code. It is not actively being supported, and should be used at your own risk, but patches are welcome.

If you would like a robust method of localization and mapping with a stereo camera or kinect, use the 2D slam_gmapping stack. See the pointcloud_to_laserscan package from the turtlebot stack and the SLAM Gmapping with Kinect Tutorial for the turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1